# WhatsApp Calls in MacOS (or Safari in general)

Tags: whatsapp, mac, safari

Using last version of MacOS and Safari (yet not sure it's related to the problem, but maybe), I'd love to know how to perform WhatsApp Calls (or Videos) from within WhatsApp Web.

From reading in the internet I saw that I need to click on the button called "create a room", but it's not existing in the three-dots button's menu, as shown in some YouTube video.

Maybe is it limited in MacOS?

Also, I've read that it's (the "rooms") are somehow related to Facebook Rooms, so maybe I have to confirm to some data-sharing between WhatsApp and Facebook?

Note to be clear, I'm not talking about any 'Desktop' version of WhatsApp, but only the browser 'web' version.

One more thing, I read that version 2.20.197.6 is the minimum version to use WhatsApp Calls - and I have more updated one, the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make voice calls in WhatsApp in MacOS by using a web browsers but you should have macOS 10.13 or newer (High Sierra). The WhatsApp Help Center doesn't mention a required version of WhatsApp for the mobile apps to be able to make voice calls, but the recommendation is always use the most recent version available for your device.

---

From [How to make a voice call > Web and Desktop](https://faq.whatsapp.com/1153602608602452/?helpref=uf_share) (emphasis mine)

> Voice calling lets you call your contacts using WhatsApp Desktop for free, even if they’re in another country. Voice calling uses your internet connection. Desktop calling is supported on Windows 10 64-bit version 1903 and newer and **macOS 10.13 and newer**. Group calls aren’t supported on WhatsApp Desktop at this time.

From [How to make a video call > Web and Desktop](https://faq.whatsapp.com/1862285217468140/?helpref=uf_share) (emphasis mine)

> Video calling lets you call your contacts using WhatsApp Desktop for free, even if they’re in another country. Video calling uses your internet connection. Desktop calling is supported on Windows 10 64-bit version 1903 and newer and **macOS 10.13 and newer**. Group calls aren’t supported on WhatsApp Desktop at this time.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I couldn't be able to find the button to make the video/voice calls from the web-browser WhatsApp. I have the most recent versions of everything. Someone can approve he can see the button? Where is it? Even by clicking the "..." button I can't see any option related.

Comment: @Cocktail Add a screenshot (show the full WhatsApp window)